# How To Implement Javascript Modules in Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, module

I want to add this [Ad Block Plus file parser module](https://github.com/minbrowser/min/tree/master/ext/abp-filter-parser-modified) to my Chrome Extension so that my background.js script can use it. Unfortunately, I don't understand how to get the `require`, and `exports` functionality. What component do I load to get that functionality in my Chrome Extension?

Comment: You don't need neither require nor exports here. That thing is a standard script that defines global variables so you can load it as any other normal script in your manifest.json's background scripts section and access the variables and functions directly. However since that script expects `exports` being defined in the global scope you'll have to define this variable yourself in a dummy script loaded before that one.

Comment: (well of course you can use webpack or another compiling/bundling tool and do as described in the readme but you will probably have to modularize your entire code, there are many tutorials so I can't suggest a particular one).